# How to change timezone of a column while fetching in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

My MySQL's timezone is UTC. I have many columns with type timestamp. All values in it are stored in UTC. I want to retrieve **only one column's date in IST format**. I do not want to modify the current dates in the column. Is there any way by which I can change the timezone while retrieving from this particular column?

I want to avoid doing CONVERT_TZ() every time when I am fetching the column. Instead, I am looking for something that will apply this function to a column by default so I do not need to do it every time.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the query to :

```
$mysqli->query("set time_zone = '+05:30'");
```

Comment: It will change the time zone for the entire MySQL. I want to change only for a particular column.

Comment: No, it will not, because its a session and global variable the above will change this for the session only [ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_time_zone)